# How to remove expressional conditions

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a long statement of conditions :

```
  public static DataGridColumn CreateAppropreateColumn(string path, PropertyInfo info, string header, IRepository repository)
    {
        DataGridColumn column = null;

        if (info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DbComboBoxAttribute), true).Any())
        {
            column = CreateComboBoxColumn(path, info, header, repository);
        }
        else if (info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescribedByteEnumComboBoxAttribute), true).Any())
        {
            column = CreateEnumComboBoxColumn(path, info, header);
        }
        else if (info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DropDownLazyLoadingDataGridAttribute), true).Any())
        {
            column = CreateDataGridDropDownLazyLoadingDataGridColumn(path, info, header, repository);
        }
        else if (info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DropDownTreeViewAttribute), true).Any())
        {
            column = CreateDataGridTreeViewColumn(path, info, header, repository);
        }
        //Other controls (Like drop down panels ... and so on ) can add here . . .
        //}
        else if (info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DatePickerAttribute), true).Any())
        {
            column = CreateDataGridDateColumn(path, info, header);
        }
        else if (info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(YearPickerAttribute), true).Any())
        {
            column = CreateDataGridYearColumn(path, info, header);
        }
        else if (info.PropertyType == typeof(bool) || info.PropertyType == typeof(bool?))
        {
            column = CreateDataGridCheckBoxColumn(path, info, header);
        }
        else
        {
            column = CreateTextBoxColumn(path, info, header);
        }
return Column;

}
```

Can I remove ifs ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way I often do such things is by creating a dictionary that maps the types to a function that creates the result, (your dictionary would be a `Dictionary<Type, Func<string, PropertyInfo, string, IRepository, DataGridColumn>>`), and then iterate over the elements of that looking for an existing attribute.

Since it is some amount of work to iterate over the attributes up the inheritance chain looking for ones of a specific type, it makes more sense to iterate over it once to create the list of attributes, then iterate over that and call the appropriate function if you find one in your dictionary. Only after the dictionary (or attributes) is exhausted would you need to have your `if`.

```
map = new Dictionary<Type, Func<string, PropertyInfo, string, IRepository, DataGridColumn>>
{
    { typeof(DbComboBoxAttribute), CreateComboBoxColumn }, // no lambda needed if CreateComboBoxColumn already matches our Func<,,,,> type
    { typeof(DescribedByteEnumComboBoxAttribute), (p, i, h, r) => CreateEnumComboBoxColumn(p, i, h) },
    ...
};
```

Then use the map like this:

```
public static DataGridColumn CreateAppropriateColumn(string path, PropertyInfo info, string header, IRepository repository)
{
    Func<string, PropertyInfo, string, IRepository, DataGridColumn>
        colfunc = null;

    // iterate over all the attributes, looking for one in our dictionary;
    // use Attribute.GetCustomAttributes because it doesn't ignore 'inherit'
    foreach (var attr in Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(info, true))
        if (map.TryGetValue(attr.GetType(), out colfunc))
            return colfunc(path, info, header, repository);

    if (info.PropertyType == typeof(bool) || info.PropertyType == typeof(bool?))
        return CreateDataGridCheckBoxColumn(path, info, header);

    return CreateTextBoxColumn(path, info, header);
}
```

Comment: Man, you beat me to it... I also want to suggest using `Dictionary`. It is the cleanest way IMHO. Moreover, the `Func<...>` can be replaced with factories for better maintainable.

Comment: @Fendy: what would those factories look like?

Comment: Just something like `interface IColumnFactory{ DataGridColumn Create(string, PropertyInfo, string, IRepository) }`

Answer (score 1):

The smallest amount of code I can think of would be similar to Gabes answer, but with the argument info in the mapping.

```
public static DataGridColumn CreateAppropreateColumn(string path, PropertyInfo info, string header, IRepository repository)
{
    //Dictionary of methods to call. Add in all your different column types here with their respective creation functions
    var columnCreationStrategy = new Dictionary<Type, Func<DataGridColumn>>()
        {
            {typeof(DbComboBoxAttribute), () => CreateComboBoxColumn(path,info,header)},
            {typeof(DescribedByteEnumComboBoxAttribute), () => CreateEnumComboBoxColumn(path,info,header, repository)}
        };

    //Just get all attributes here, then return the first successful match
    var attributeList = info.GetCustomAttributes(true).ToList();
    foreach (var attribute in attributeList)
    {
        var type = attribute.GetType();
        if (columnCreationStrategy.ContainsKey(type))
            return columnCreationStrategy[type].Invoke();
    }
    //Maybe throw some exception here? Depends on how you want to handle it. You could even have a default column generation method here
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The problem with your solution is that it has to create the dictionary anew with every call to the method, where each lambda is a new object that has to be constructed. It's not much in the scheme of things, but why do the extra work? You also need to put in the `if`s at the end, because those say what to do if there is no attribute.

Comment: Ahh true. I will remember that next time I need to create a mapping for methods with different signatures :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it would be nicer, but you would use the ternary operator:

```
DataGridColumn column = info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DbComboBoxAttribute), true).Any()
        ? CreateComboBoxColumn(path, info, header, repository)
    : info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescribedByteEnumComboBoxAttribute), true).Any()
        ? CreateEnumComboBoxColumn(path, info, header)
    : info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DropDownLazyLoadingDataGridAttribute), true).Any()
        ? CreateDataGridDropDownLazyLoadingDataGridColumn(path, info, header, repository)
    : info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DropDownTreeViewAttribute), true).Any()
    ...
        : CreateTextBoxColumn(path, info, header);
```

The basic form is

```
value = condition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse;
```

And it can be chained:

```
value = condition ? valueIfTrue : condition2 ? valueIfCond2True : valueIfBothFalse
```

Though I've heard it said that the ternary operator was invented to confuse poor comp-sci students. In this case, I'm not sure it's any clearer.

Comment: Man, don't ternary for over than 1 condition. It's a nightmare to debug it.

Comment: Now that I look more closely, the last paragraph of my suggestion doesn't apply here. I thought that in some cases, path, info, header,, and repository would be null, (and you could use that to determine which column function to call), but I now see you're not setting these variables the way I had thought. (Sorry, careless reading.)

Answer (score 0):

I normally collect all the stuff and then loop through:

```
    public static DataGridColumn CreateAppropreateColumn(string path, PropertyInfo info, string header, IRepository repository)
    {
        var criteria = new Dictionary<Type, Func<string, PropertyInfo, string, IRepository, DataGridColumn>>();

        criteria.Add(typeof(DbComboBoxAttribute), CreateComboBoxColumn);
        criteria.Add(typeof(DescribedByteEnumComboBoxAttribute)), CreateEnumComboBoxColumn);
        criteria.Add(typeof(DropDownLazyLoadingDataGridAttribute), CreateDataGridDropDownLazyLoadingDataGridColumn);
        // add more here - in the order you desired...            

        // loop through and return out if there is a matched one
        foreach (Type t in criteria.Keys)
        {
            if (info.GetCustomAttributes(t, true).Any())
            {
                return criteria[t].Invoke(path, info, header, repository);
            }
        }

        // Default Return here:
        return CreateTextBoxColumn(path, info, header);
    }
```

Edit: 
did not see Gabe's answer, which looks more elegant.